# Comparing cluserting structure of two datasets

Tags: clustering, goodness-of-fit, dendrogram

I have two datasets, one with probands of a certain disease in it, the other has their siblings in it. Both of them contain the exact same variables (some phenotypes). Now, I would like to compare the similarity/difference between the clustering structures of probands and siblings, so that I could have an idea of what phenotypes or groups of phenotypes to pay attention to when analysing the genetic cause of this disease.

I suppose the cor_cophenetic() in the *dendextend* R package could be useful. However, the error message of 'incompatible scales' keeps showing. My problematic codes are as following:

```
library(cluster)
data_scaled <- scale(proband_data)
d <- daisy(data_scaled, metric = "gower")
fit.average <- hclust(d, method = "average")

sib_data_scaled <- scale(sib_data)
sib_d <- daisy(sib_data_scaled, metric = "gower")
sib.fit.average <- hclust(sib_d, method = "average")

library(dendextend)
dend_pro <- as.dendrogram (fit.average)
dend_sib <- as.dendrogram (sib.fit.average)

dend_list <- dendlist(dend_pro,dend_sib)
cor.dendlist(dend_list, method = "cophenetic")
```

So, I'm wondering where did I go wrong, or what else should I try. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I think your question would be better suited for Stack Overflow with R tags. When you post questions about coding in R, it's always best to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That is the fastest way to get great answers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Kat. I think my real question is that what method/strategy could fit here and how could I compare clustering structures generated from different datasets.